# Whats the best way to hide elements when the data attribute doesn't match?

Tags: jquery, html

Consider the following:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#num-locations input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      dataId = e.target.dataset.location;
      console.log(dataId);
      $('.jobs-listing [data-city]').not('[data-city*="'+dataId+'"]').hide();
    } else {
      $('.jobs-listing [data-city]').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Here's an example of the HTML, there could be tons of these:

```
<div class="manage-wrapper  d-flex py-5 eachJob" data-city="Ottawa" data-province="Ontario">
    <div class="manage-text w-7">
        <h4 class="font-weight-bold mt-0 mb-1 job-title"></h4>
        <p class="job-description"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="manage-aside text-right w-3">
        <h4 class="font-weight-bold mt-0 mb-1 job-location">Ottawa</h4>
        <p class="mb-0 job-province">Ontario</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary job-url" tabindex="-1">VIEW JOB</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

- **Expected**: Apply display none, only to the parent div, in this case `'.manage-wrapper'`
- **Actual**: Everything on the page is hidden, because a "display: none" is applied to every dive inside the `.manage-wrapper` but not applied to the `.manage-wrapper` it's self.
- There are no console errors when you click said checkbox.

**Whats the proper way to apply**: *`display: none` to any div with a class `manage-wrapper` upon click when the `data-location` does not match the `data-city`?*

**[And]**

**When You uncheck said checkbox, whats the proper way to restore the "hidden" elements?**

Comment: Where should data-location be within your html?

Comment: @MattBunch I left a comment on your proposed answer, hope that clears up the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly simplified, but should get you going.

```js
$('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#num-locations input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    $.each($('.manage-wrapper'), function(key, value) {
      if ($(value).data('location') != $(value).data('city')) {
        $(value).hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num-locations">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="manage-wrapper  d-flex py-5 eachJob" data-city="Ottawa" data-province="Ontario">
  <div class="manage-text w-7">
    <h4 class="font-weight-bold mt-0 mb-1 job-title"></h4>
    <p class="job-description"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="manage-aside text-right w-3">
    <h4 class="font-weight-bold mt-0 mb-1 job-location">Ottawa</h4>
    <p class="mb-0 job-province">Ontario</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary job-url" tabindex="-1">VIEW JOB</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that the checkbox is not with in the div `manage-wrapper` it is in a sidebar under a div called `#num-locations` Hence why I have:  `$('#num-locations input[type="checkbox"]'` I want to hide all `manage-wrapper`'s that don't match that checkboxe's data-id (in this case, the value might be `Ottwa`)

Comment: @TheWebs I've made a few changes, let me know if this does/doesnt work for you.